# How to extract digits from a sentence in java?

Tags: java

```
[{"id":1475280000,"high":0.01384629,"low":0.01155011,"area":13251.43990321,"quoteVolume":1073925.2309893,"averagevolume":0.01233925},{"id":1475366400,"high":0.0139987,"low":0.0119,"area":7535.00823446,"quoteVolume":573093.11152305,"averagevolume":0.01314796}]
```

Above is the data from which i want to extract digits. I want to extract id, area and average volume from above data and print the result in the form:

```
id1:1475280000
area1:13251.43990321
averagevolume1:0.01233925

id2:1475366400
area2:7535.00823446
averagevolume3:0.01314796
```

Comment: your "sentence" is a json object... you need to parse that either to string or a pojo

Comment: What do you have? Is it array of maps with one map? Give us some code. [mcve]. I want to help but it's impossible at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to be more specific about the help you need. Currently your question is really just asking someone to explain how to write the code. Please have a go at a solution and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Is this data a in a String or an Object?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the json object wrapping the values in a Java object using jackson fasterxml and ObjectMapper:

```java
class Values{
  //With getters and setters
  int id;
  double area;
  double averageVolume;
  //Rest of the values in the json string
}
```

Then your deserializer might look like:

```
public class Deserialize {
  private final ObjectMapper mapper;
   public DeserializeCollectionMessage() {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   }

   public Values deSerializeCollectionMessage(String jsonString) {
      Values val = new Values();
      return mapper.readValue(jsonString, Values.class);
}
```

Then you can extract the values from the Values object